# How to join when using groupby

Tags: sql, linq, lambda

I have two tables of picturedetails and picture likes  in mydatabase.

```
public partial class picturedetail
{
    public int idpictures { get; set; }
    public int iduser { get; set; }
    public string picTitle { get; set; }
    public string picFilename { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime pictime { get; set; }
    public int likes { get; set; }
    public int nuditylevel { get; set; }
    public int fakeslevel { get; set; }
}

  public partial class picturelike
{
    public int idpicturelike { get; set; }
    public int idpictures { get; set; }
    public int iduser { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime iddatetime { get; set; }
    public int iduserlikedby { get; set; }
    public int likenumber { get; set; }
}
```

Its my Data Transfer Object (DTO) to avoid anonymous type error

```
  public class LikesandPictureDetails
{
    public int IdPicturess { get; set; }
    public int IdUserPic { get; set; }
    public string PicTitle { get; set; }
    public string picFilename { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? PicTime { get; set; }
    public int Likes { get; set; }
    public int NudityLevel { get; set; }
    public int FakesLevel { get; set; }
    public int IdPicturelike { get; set; }
    public int IdUser { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? IdDatetime { get; set; }
    public int IduserLikedby { get; set; }
    public int LikeNumber { get; set; }
    public int IdPictures { get; set; }
    public float totalrating { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

I am successfully able to count the individual ratings of the picture and then divide by their counts. Now i want to show totalrating in my picture details table. How to achieve this thing? This is my code:

```
var query =
            db.picturelikes.GroupBy(n => n.idpictures).Select(group =>
                     new LikesandPictureDetails
                     {
                         IdPictures = group.Key,
                         totalrating = (group.AsEnumerable().Sum(o => o.individualrating)) / group.Count(),

                     });
```

here likesandpicturedetails is acting as a dto.

Comment: And what is the question? How to join you query result to ...?

Comment: the question is to how to ammend the total rating in the picturedetails table.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all you should use method [Average](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average.aspx) to calculate average value. But in your case 
 But, as you need to calculate overall rating, why don't you calculate sum and average in the same step:

```
 db.picturelikes.GroupBy(n => n.idpictures).Select(group =>
 new LikesandPictureDetails
 {
     IdPictures = group.Key,
     averageRating = (group.AsEnumerable().Average(o => o.individualrating)),
     totalRating = (group.AsEnumerable().Sum(o => o.individualrating)),     
 });
```

Comment: So what's you problem? You can't apply already calculated values with your picture markup? You do have ID of picture in those precalculated groups. Just take one correcponding to your picture using `Where` linq clause.

Comment: The problem is how to add those values in my picturedetails table.

Comment: Do you mean in some kind of POCO class to model or you want to update db? Please edit your OP with info what needs to be changed, and what structure it has.

Comment: @Hmmmmmmmmmm, are you sure? Seems no changes were made.

Comment: changed now , it didnt save last time.